# Slow plan generation on QGIS

Tags: qgis, performance, hardware-recommendations

I am currently using QGIS version 3.36. I often have to generate plans in several formats (A0, A3, etc.). The problem is that every time I decrease or increase the scale, the loading time is often significant. The display jerks when I use the tools to move the plan.

Would there be software programming required to compensate for these slowdowns?

Also, could you tell me what are the recommended characteristics of a computer that meets the resources requested by the QGIS software?

Comment: Before looking at hardware limits or customizing QGIS's code, inspect your data. Data type (WMS with slow network requests?) Quantity being drawn (Millions of polygons?), features complexity, spatial index, data projection == view projection etc)

Comment: PC min 32GB of RAM?

Comment: Maybe you need a better graphics card?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.